# Replace a couple of strings of text automatically?

Tags: automation, regex, find-and-replace, text-editing, string

More detailed:

I've got a folder with data for a game which code is pure text and customizable (M.U.G.E.N). Beside all other things, the *.cns file of each character contains following string of text:

```
;def file for char
Life = 2334 (could be any number from 100 to 99999) ;default value is 1000
Attack = 123 (could be any number from 1 to 99999) ; 100
Defence = 157 (could be any number from 1 to 99999) ; 100
```

But instead of default set for their value as standard (Life = 1000, Attack = 100, Defence = 100), they're quite unbalanced as the uploader of that game messingly (*randomly*) change their value by his weird references. Now my problem is I want to reset all their value back to default without go through all the *.cns file (hundreds, maybe more) and edit those line myself. How can I do that efficiently?

I want something like,
Search all ***.cns** file content in the folder and detect the line which includes *"Life = *" "Attack = *" and "Defence = *"* (not case sensitive) and replace them with "Life = 1000", "Attack = 100"... and so on without care about the certain number behide the "=") And as automatical as possible.

I google a little bit and think maybe some kind of regex find replace method in some advanced text editor can help, but I don't quite get it... can anyone give a hand and explain step by step for me how to do? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

On linux (or on windows using cygwin) you can use

```
find . -name '*.cns'
```

to find all files with '.cns' extension under the current directory.

You can use 'sed' to edit the files "inline"

```
find . -name '*.cns' -exec \
sed -i~ 's/Life.*/Life = 1000/g;s/Attack.*/Attack = 100/g;s/Defence.*/Defence = 100/g' "{}" \;
```